# Errors : Cannot use import statement outside a module THREE.OrbitControl

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im starting with three.js. After trying to implement orbit controls i have some errors. It looks simple but i cannot find a good solution for my errors. When im trying to implement controls like :

`var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);`

im getting these errors

[Cannot use import statement outside a module and THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVPs7.png)

I added both threejs and orbitcontrols just before starting a new script. What am I doing wrong here?

```
        <script src="scripts/three.js"></script>   
        <script src="scripts/OrbitControls.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var camera = new
                THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                renderer.setClearColor(0x888888,1)
                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: If you're using yarn/npm you can `import * as THREE from 'three-full'` just make sure to add/install the `three-full` package. `three-full` has some extra helpers like THREE.GLTFLoader.

Answer (score 2):

**Online Resource, Threejs Host, Sample Code**

---

```
           <script type="module">
            import * as THREE from 'https://three.ipozal.com/threejs/resources/threejs/r110/build/three.module.js';
            import { OrbitControls } from 'https://three.ipozal.com/threejs/resources/threejs/r110/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
            import { OBJLoader2 } from 'https://three.ipozal.com/threejs/resources/threejs/r110/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader2.js';

            function main() {
.....
</script>
```

Comment: hi kaveh, could you write some clarification on code you posted?

Comment: The "import" command was confused for some developers, to make this simple we can run share host for needed modules for import and use full URL in import command.
in above code the "https://three.ipozal.com" is the share host that is the copy of threejs node project on github.
and there is some point like:
use this html tag for threejs main script block
<script type="module">

Comment: hi, is there a solution where my whole code is NOT in my index.html? that's pretty messy

Comment: @clockw0rk maybe ur whole code not write in the index.html, but in compile time the whole code will be collect in ur index page....then u should have no problem. if have? then talk about ur errors.

Answer (score 1):

### Jest solution

The examples that ship in the npm module have not been built and would need to be transformed.

Because I'm not testing these files themselves I just stub them out:

```js
//jest.config.js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'three/examples/jsm/': '<rootDir/config/jest/mockUndefined.js'
  }

//config/jest/mockUndefined.js
module.exports = undefined
```

If you really need to include them in tests, a `ts-jest` solution would look like this:

```js
//jest.config.js
{
  //slow preset - does many extra transforms
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts-esm',
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!(three/examples/jsm)/)'],
```

Be warned, the second solution is much slower as now jest has to transform many extra files.

Comment: Your solutions, doesn't solve the actual problem

Comment: It solves the problem of getting the error mentioned in the OP when running Jest tests.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your version of `OrbitControls.js` is a ES6 module. That means you have to import the controls like so:

```js
<script type="module">

    import * as THREE from 'scripts/three.module.js';
    import { OrbitControls } from 'scripts/OrbitControls.js';

     var scene = new THREE.Scene();

     var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(0x888888,1)
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

Notice that the above code uses the [three.module.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/build/three.module.js) build file which you can find in the build directory of the official git repository. If you are not familiar with ES6 modules, I suggest you study an existing resource about this topic. E.g. https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

`three.js R109`

Comment: This seems unlikely to work correctly given that `OrbitControls.js` looks for `../../../build/three.module.js`

Comment: Yes, the OP needs to adjust the path of `three.module.js` in `OrbitControls` to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was including type="module" as @kaveh-eyni mentioned but then npm installing the "deprecated" modules directly into my project.

- `npm install --save three-orbitcontrols`
- `npm i --save three-gltf-loader`

and then

```
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'three/build/three.module'
import OrbitControls from 'three-orbitcontrols'
import GLTFLoader from 'three-gltf-loader
```