# Three.js Uncaught Syntax error : Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: three.js, 3d, gltf, uncaught-exception

I'm trying to implement a 3d design file (gltf) into a website with three.js and I'm keeping having this error:

[image: Error Capture]

Here is the html/Javascript/CSS code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8 />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test2.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="../three_import/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../three_import/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="../three_import/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    
    <script>
      let scene, camera, renderer;

      function init() {

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
        controls.addEventListener('change', renderer);

        hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight (0x404040,100);
        scene.add(hlight);

        let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load('../Image/USB.gltf', function(gltf){
          car = gltf.scene.children[0];
          car.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
          scene.add(gltf.scene);
          animate();
        });
      }
      function animate() {
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
      init();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have no idea what this error could come from, and I've tried everything given in othersites and it doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Errors : Cannot use import statement outside a module THREE.OrbitControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58363166/errors-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-three-orbitcontrol)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is true: Your main `script` tag is of type `text/javascript`, not `module`.

In your `HTML`, you ***don't*** need:

```html
<script src="../three_import/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="../three_import/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="../three_import/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
```

Instead, you would do this to your main `script` tag:

```js
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from '../three_import/three.min.js';
import {OrbitControls} from '../three_import/OrbitControls.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from '../three_import/GLTFLoader.js';
//Your code here
</script>
```

Remember, since we are doing this, instead of doing `new THREE.OrbitControls()` or `new THREE.GLTFLoader()`, we would use `new OrbitControls()` and `new GLTFLoader()`.  ***(without the `THREE`)***

That's all!